# How to Preselect item in ChoiceChip Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

As the title says, I wonder how can we pre-select an item in ChoiceChip?

The scenario is like this:

- Users click an item from the ListTodo page.
- One of the data items, namely "label" is passed to another screen called the DetailTodo page. The value is an integer.
- If the value of the label = 0, then the Pre-selected ChoiceChip item is Personal. If the label value = 1, then what is selected when the page is opened is Work. etc.

Here's my code:

```
ChoiceChip(
                                    label: Text(
                                      labelOptions[index],
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Color(0xffffffff),
                                        fontSize: 12,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    selected: selectedOption == index,
                                    onSelected: (selected) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        selectedOption = index;
                                        print(selectedOption);
                                      });
                                      print(labelOptions[index]);
                                    },
                                    selectedColor: Colors.black,
                                    backgroundColor: Color(0xff898989),
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                                      side: BorderSide(
                                        color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                                        width: 1,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
```

In the above code "selectedOption" contains the data that have passed before. How might we achieve that, so that when ever users open the DetailTodo(), one of the options is preselected based on the value of "selectedOption"?

I have tried to Googling the solution, but have not found any feasible solution. It seems that there's no way to do this

Answer (score 0):

To pre-select the ChoiceChip, you can set the initial value of selectedOption in the initState method of your DetailTodo widget. Here's an example:

```dart
class DetailTodo extends StatefulWidget {
  final int selectedOption;

  DetailTodo({required this.selectedOption});

  @override
  DetailTodoState createState() => DetailTodoState();
}

class _DetailTodoState extends State<DetailTodo> {
  late int selectedOption;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedOption = widget.selectedOption;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Your code for ChoiceChip goes here
  }
}
```

Navigation example:

```dart
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => DetailTodo(selectedOption: 1), // Pass the selectedOption value here
  ),
);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting

I've set the value of "selectedOption" in initState(). But, I'm still figuring out how to use the value of it to pre-select the ChoiceChip and make the selected item have different background whenever user open the DetailTodo()